# MFC CLisCtrl: How do I get notified when the user has reordered columns?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, mfc

I added the LVS_EX_HEADERDRAGDROP style which allows users to drag columns around:

```
myListControl_.SetView(LVS_REPORT);
myListControl_.SetExtendedStyle(LVS_EX_HEADERDRAGDROP);
```

This is working fine. However, how do I get notified when the user has reordered the columns, so that I can save the new ordering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ON_NOTIFY_EX(HDN_ENDDRAG, 0, OnHeaderEndDragMethod)
```

[Header_GetOrderArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775399%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Actually turns out there is a problem with this because in the handler for this event the new column order does not appear to be available yet via `GetColumnOrderArray`

Comment: DL the project from [Code Project: CListCtrl Which Can Show and Hide Columns](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28787/CListCtrl-Which-Can-Show-and-Hide-Columns). If you delve into the CListCtrl_Column_Picker::OnHeaderEndDrag method you'll see that the pNMH->pitem->iOrder gives you the new position number of the column that was dragged. Add an event listener for HDN_BEGINDRAG to get the column's original position and from there you can get the change in column orders.