# Get Column Order (MFC)

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, clistctrl

I'm trying to get the order of the columns in an MFC `CListCtrl`. Initially I tried calling `GetColumnOrderArray()` in a message handler for the `HDN_ENDDRAG` notification, but that always returned the old (pre-drag and drop) column order. So, based on the advice in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559970/mfc-clisctrl-how-do-i-get-notified-when-the-user-has-reordered-columns#comment17395380_10560728) SO post's comment, I tried handling both the `HDN_BEGINDRAG` and the `HDN_ENDDRAG` and grabbing the old and new column orders with `phdr->pitem->iOrder`. But `pitem` is always NULL for me in the both handlers. No idea why.

SOOO I tried using the column index stored in the message (`phdr->iItem`) to talk directly to the `CHeaderCtrl` and grab the column order myself, but the fields in the structure populated by my header control were all invalid; I still couldn't get the column order.

Is there some sort of deeper problem with my list control? Or am I just handling messages incorrectly?

`HDN_BEGINDRAG` message handler:

```
BOOL CDFAManListView::OnHdnBegindrag(UINT, NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    LPNMHEADER phdr = reinterpret_cast<LPNMHEADER>(pNMHDR);

    phdr->iItem; // this contains a valid column index

    HDITEM columnStruct;

    List->GetHeaderCtrl()->GetItem(phdr->iItem, &columnStruct); // but this call just fills columnStruct with junk values

    if (phdr->pitem) // pitem is always null
    {
        initialPosition = phdr->pitem->iOrder;
    }

    *pResult = 0;
    return TRUE;
}
```

`HDN_ENDDRAG` message handler:

```
void CDFAManListView::OnHdnEnddrag(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    LPNMHEADER phdr = reinterpret_cast<LPNMHEADER>(pNMHDR);

    HDITEM columnStruct;

    List->GetHeaderCtrl()->GetItem(phdr->iItem, &columnStruct); // still just fills columnStruct with junk

    List->GetColumnOrderArray(signalColumnOrder); // gets **old** column order

    *pResult = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this is an old question, I came across it just now while looking into CListCtrl column dragging and thought I'd update it a bit in case it's of use to somebody else.

The OP mentioned that,

```
HDITEM columnStruct;

List->GetHeaderCtrl()->GetItem(phdr->iItem, &columnStruct); // but this call just fills columnStruct with junk values
```

This will because you haven't initialised columnStruct enough to tell GetItem what data you're interested in retrieving. You need to initialise columnStruct.mask with various flags such as HDI_WIDTH | HDI_ORDER, and if you use HDI_TEXT then give columnStruct.pszText a buffer and columnStruct.cchTextMax the size of the buffer.

This is [documented in the CHeaderCtrl::GetItem documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/82shyz02.aspx) for example.

> Any flags set in the mask element ensure that values in the
>   corresponding elements are properly filled in upon return. If the mask
>   element is set to zero, values in the other structure elements are
>   meaningless.

Comment: Lovely, I just didn't read the documentation carefully enough -.-

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit of simplistic solution, why not call `GetColumnOrderArray()` when the parent of the list control needs to be closed?

If you do need the column order for some other purpose right away and from the SO post you quoted, it looks like `HDN_ENDDRAG` is too early to call `GetColumnOrderArray()`, try a `PostMessage` to the (parent of) the list control at the end of `OnHdnEnddrag()` with the message number in the range `WM_USER through 0x7FFF` and call `GetColumnOrderArray()` in the handler of that message.

Comment: I tried your first solution already by calling `GetColumnOrderArray()` from the destructor of the `CListView` that contained my list control, but the list control is already invalid by that point; the program crashed :( I'll see if I can get your second solution working, but `PostMessage()` doesn't give you a firm idea of when the message will get processed, right? I can't guarantee that the parent will process the message AFTER the `HDN_ENDDRAG` handler completes and `GetColumnArray()` would return a valid answer?

Comment: I'm sure that the destructor is too late, that's why I mentioned "when the parent of the list control needs to be closed", so that will be before the close-process starts; what kind of a parent class do you use to host the ListControl?
`PostMessage` will process the message only after it has finished processing all the other queue messages, it's worth a try

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try. And the parent is a `CListView`. I was trying to call `GetColumnOrderArray()` from the destructor of the `CListView`, not the `CListCtrl()`.

Comment: I ended up just creating my own `SaveState()` function that I call elsewhere in the program (for the sake of time; your solution might work perfectly fine, idk). I don't like it since it's not done in an automatically called function like a message notification, but it works :/ Thanks for your time!

Comment: I'm glad the input was helpful [we normally save the view-settings in our applications when the view is about to be closed and not during the actual change itself (like drag and drop), that way you can re-order the columns any number of times and the setting is saved only once, when you close]

Comment: See, that's why I was trying it in the list view's destructor ("when the view is about to be closed"). As it stands, I store the order array in a member of my list view class every time I repopulate the list, then save that to the registry in the list view's destructor.